# Symmetric procedural material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I've modelled a shape which is symmetric along z axis. I used material and some texure with generated coordinates plugged in displacement node. Everything is distributed evenly on the mesh. 
I would like that material is also mirror image along z.

So that a procedural texture on one side of z axis 
is the mirror image of other side of z axis.

How to achieve this with nodes?

[image]

Comment: An image of the material you are working on would be helpful, different textures (wood, stone, etc.)can be manipulated differently.  Have you tried using a *geometry input* node? Try using the position output.

Comment: It's noise and magic texture in that order. Where to plug geometry node to get symmetry along z ?

Comment: @Timaroberts , I've added the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mix Color

First step is to mask out the surface's point that be affected by the flipping of the coordinates.

In order to get the reference needed we should start by adding a **Texture** coordinates node and pick the **Object** coordinates
   type (if you are interest in the local Z)

Then add a **Separate XYZ** to get the Z component of the coordinates and filter out the values greater than `0` with the help of a **Math** node

[image]

If the origin of the object belongs to the simmetry plane, all we have to do is to flip the input coordinates (Generate type in the shown example) with a **Mapping** node (notice the -1 value for the Z scale parameter) and mix them with a **Mix** node whose inpuct factor is the mask we created before.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll try but on the first read I didn't get the logic of it. I have to learn the nodes.

Comment: How to make this extra circle before mapping node?

Comment: By pressing Shift and left-dragging with the mouse over the wire. Or you can find it in the *Add* menu in *Layout*. It is called *Reroute node*